# MySQL Query Takes A Long Time To Find POIs by Latitude and Longitude

Tags: mysql

I have 17 million points of interest in a MySQL table (v5.0.77), with several fields, including name,lat,lng, and category. Lat and Long are of type Decimal(10,6), and Category is a Small Integer. I have an multi-column index on lat,lng,category.

My queries to find points within 2km of location take a long time - on average about 120 seconds.

If I query from exactly the same center point, I can tell that the query is cached b/c the query executes in less than second. As soon as I change the center point, the query takes a long time again.

I do my calculation to determine the bounds of the area I'm searching outside of the query, versus a distance calculation within it, which is the source of a lot of reports you see about similar queries taking a long time.

Here's an example from the Slow Query Log:

```
Query_time: 177  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 2841  Rows_examined: 28691

SELECT p.id, p.name AS name, p.lat, p.lng, c.name AS category
FROM poi AS p 
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON p.category = c.id
WHERE p.lat BETWEEN 37.524993 AND 37.560965 AND p.lng BETWEEN -77.491776 AND -77.446408;
```

I feel like the server is tuned correctly - I have enough memory, it's just me using it for development, I feel I've tweaked MySQL settings appropriately.

This has really stumped me for a while now. Shouldn't MySQL be able to very efficiently scan the index I've created? Should I convert to spatial data types, or use Sphinx to improve query speed? Any thoughts/perspective much appreciated.

Comment: include the index, and execution plan, please

Comment: Are you sure your query is using the multi-column index that you have mentioned? Please try doing an EXPLAIN of your query. I think it might help if you change your multi-column index to include only (`lat`, `lon`) columns and remove `category` from it. It might also make sense to possibly split your data into multiple tables based on category or whatever you deem fit but that comes only if nothing else works

Comment: Here it is. It is using the index:
`id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE p range Lat,Lng,Category Lat,Lng,Category 12 NULL 23774 Using where
1 SIMPLE c eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 2 p.category 1`

Comment: @Abhay I removed the left join on the category table from the query and it still takes a long time.

Comment: The explain seems quite okay, doesn't show anything that is weird. Even from the slow query log, the rows_examined isn't that huge. I guess this is the subject of further analysis. It probably seems that MySQL might be doing quite a few disk read-writes considering the size of the table. Can you please try fine-tuning some of the MySQL's environment variables, like key_buffer_size and read_buffer_size. This post might be helpful - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/

Comment: After everyone's comments, I modified the query. If I remove the non-index fields from the where clause, then the query is fast (less than a second). As soon as I modify it to select something not part of the multicolumn index I have on (lat,lng,category), it goes to 3 minutes. I've tried variations on this multiple times and it's the same result. Note that I'm putting the non-index field in the select statement, not the where statement. Per my understanding of indexes, it shouldn't matter if I put addtl fields in the select, if I am still using the index in the where. @Abhay

Comment: @Abhay and others, I was able to get the query to work quickly by creating an index on all the fields in the select and where clauses, not just those in the where clause. Per my understanding of indexes, I expected that if my index covered the fields in the where clause I'd be ok, but this didn't seem to be the case here. I also converted to InnoDB, but this had marginal impact until I redefined my index. Anyhoodle, problem solved...

Comment: @LeeL, great that it now works. But it intrigues me that indexing the SELECT columns quickens the query. Well, I'll try to explore this more. But I now think it might have helped if we only add the LEFT JOIN columns and the WHERE columns to the index, leaving the SELECT ones out; not sure though. And thank you for letting know of the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the spacial extension in mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html)? I think that you can get better performance in your database if you use the date type "geometry" as and index and search using the rectangle created by the latitude-longitude. (info about the type geometry http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html).

I´ve used it with a database with 150k. places and the query responds in few miliseconds.

Comment: can you post an example please?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem extreme, but you could hard code logic into your inserts, updates and retrieval procedures to look at the `category` field, and select the table that matches the `category` type you're looking for. Yes, that means you'll have tables dedicated specifically for a certain category, and this may come off as too heavy handed for most, and complicate maintenance later. But if your categories are not modified often (GPS coordinates don't strike me as something that will change anytime soon), you might want to consider it.

Comment: Droograns, do you mean making sharding by the category?

Comment: Hmmm. Never heard that term before. [This website](http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/) mentions a term called `Table Partitioning` that seems to match what I was thinking...though it recommends doing the partitioning logically, whereas this is a bit more permanent...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture), i´m not saying it´s a bad idea, but i think that it is dangerous and expensive for developing. Using apropiate indexes like spatial i that case could be more appropiate.

Comment: To be blunt, I agree. The OP's claim that a query, sifting through 17 million records in 120 seconds, makes me think there are more reasonable options available. But if the OPs POI continue to grow, sharding by category will pay off (eventually). Thanks for introducing me to a new term!